# Verifying Signed Xml Generated From Java In NET

Tags: certificate, java, .net, validation, xml

I have the below XML,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<Response xmlns="http://www.site.ae/g">
  <Message xml:id="message">
    <Header>
      <Service>Read</Service>
      <Action>SomeAction</Action>
    </Header>
    <Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="SomeDataType">
      <Status>Success</Status>
      <Data>
        <Id>123</Id>
      </Data>
    </Body>
  </Message>
  <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
    <SignedInfo>
      <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315#WithComments"/>
      <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256"/>
      <Reference URI="#message">
        <Transforms>
          <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/>
        </Transforms>
        <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
        <DigestValue>SomeValue</DigestValue>
      </Reference>
    </SignedInfo>
    <SignatureValue>
      SomeValue
    </SignatureValue>
    <KeyInfo>
      <X509Data>
        <X509Certificate>
          SomeValue
        </X509Certificate>
      </X509Data>
    </KeyInfo>
  </Signature>
</Response>
```

The above XML genereted from a java application. The java application team provided us 3 certificate to verify the above xml. I have created 3 objects in C#,

```
var clientCert = new X509Certificate2("clientCert.cer");
var intermediateCert = new X509Certificate2("intermediateCert.cer");
var rootCert = new X509Certificate2("rootCert.cer");
```

One is root, second one is intermediate and third one is certificate. I have created the below code,

```
var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.PreserveWhitespace = true;
xmlDoc.Load("above.xml");
bool result = VerifyXml(xmlDoc, clientCert);

    private static Boolean VerifyXml(XmlDocument Doc, X509Certificate2 Key)
    {
        // Create a new SignedXml object and pass it
        // the XML document class.
        var signedXml = new System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.SignedXml(Doc);

        // Find the "Signature" node and create a new XmlNodeList object.
        XmlNodeList nodeList = Doc.GetElementsByTagName("Signature");

        // Throw an exception if no signature was found.
        if (nodeList.Count <= 0)
        {
            throw new CryptographicException("Verification failed: No Signature was found in the document.");
        }

        // Though it is possible to have multiple signatures on 
        // an XML document, this app only supports one signature for
        // the entire XML document.  Throw an exception 
        // if more than one signature was found.
        if (nodeList.Count >= 2)
        {
            throw new CryptographicException("Verification failed: More that one signature was found for the document.");
        }

        // Load the first <signature> node.  
        signedXml.LoadXml((XmlElement)nodeList[0]);

        // Check the signature and return the result.
        return signedXml.CheckSignature(Key, true);
    }
```

But the above code result is always return false. Is there is something I am missing? Is .NET support verifying the xml generated from java?

Got Answer from
[Verify SignatureValue And DigestValue Using Sha256 RSA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67357230/verify-signaturevalue-and-digestvalue-using-sha256-rsa)

Comment: Can you verify the signature is valid with Java? Is the certificate and it's chain trusted?

Comment: @DanielFisherlennybacon I got the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67357230/verify-signaturevalue-and-digestvalue-using-sha256-rsa Thanks